# How can I get built electron app PDB file

Tags: javascript, windows, electron, windbg, dump

I made a simple electron app using crashReporter and electron-builder.

When My app occurred crash, dump file generated successfully.

I try to analyzing dump file with winDbg but it is impossible because I cannot find my electron app's PDB file.

I already downloaded electron PDB and windows PDB file following this documents (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/development/setting-up-symbol-server).

I also try added electron-builder build options [includePdb](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration) but my electron app does not generate PDB file.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You made an Electron app, right? You did not write a native Electron Node module (see [C++ Addon](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html))? If I understood that correctly, you write Javascript code which gets packaged into the Electron app. There is no PDB then.

Comment: @ThomasWeller You can package your Electron app in an exe file. If there is a crash somewhere, it's better if you have the PDB. Legit question, imho. I am currently having the exact same "problem"...